# Masking horizontal and vertical lines with Open CV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to remove horizontal and vertical lines in this image in order to have more distinct text areas.

[image]

I'm using the below code, which follows this [guide](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d1/dee/tutorial_moprh_lines_detection.html)

```
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
                    blurred, 255,
                    cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,
                    25,
                    15
                )
# Create the images that will use to extract the horizontal and vertical lines
horizontal = np.copy(thresh)
vertical = np.copy(thresh)

# Specify size on horizontal axis
cols = horizontal.shape[1]
horizontal_size = math.ceil(cols / 20)

# Create structure element for extracting horizontal lines through morphology operations
horizontalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (horizontal_size, 1))

# Apply morphology operations
horizontal = cv2.erode(horizontal, horizontalStructure)
horizontal = cv2.dilate(horizontal, horizontalStructure)

# Show extracted horizontal lines
cv2.imwrite("horizontal.jpg", horizontal)

# Specify size on vertical axis
rows = vertical.shape[0]
verticalsize = math.ceil(rows / 20)

# Create structure element for extracting vertical lines through morphology operations
verticalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, verticalsize))

# Apply morphology operations
vertical = cv2.erode(vertical, verticalStructure)
vertical = cv2.dilate(vertical, verticalStructure)
```

After this, I know I would need to isolate the lines and mask the original image with the white lines, however I'm not really sure on how to proceed.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: do you want to mask using both the vertical and horizontal lines?

Comment: yes both vertical and horizontal lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found a solution by using part of Juke's suggestion. Eventually I would need to continue to process the image using a binary mode so figured I might keep it that way.

First, add the resulting images of `vertical` and `horizontal`. This will give you an image containing both the horizontal and vertical lines. Since both the images are of type uint8 (unsigned 8-bit integer) adding them won't be a problem:

```
res = vertical + horizontal
```

Then, subtract `res` from the original input image `tresh`, which was used to find the lines. This will remove the white lines and can than be used to apply some other morphology transformations.

```
fin = thresh - res
```

Answer (score 3):

[Jeru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51384052/7328782) already gives you what you want. But I wanted to add an alternative that is maybe a bit more general than what you have so far.

You are converting the color image to gray-value, then apply adaptive threshold in an attempt to find lines. You filter this to get only the long horizontal and vertical lines, then use that mask to paint the original image white at those locations.

Here we look for all lines, and remove them from the image making painting them with whatever the surrounding color is. This process does not involve thresholding at all, all morphological operations are applied to the channels of the color image.

Ideally we'd use color morphology, but implementations of that are rare. Mathematical morphology is based on maximum and minimum operations, and the maximum or minimum of a color triplet (i.e. a vector) is not well defined.

So instead we apply the following procedure to each of the three color channels independently. This should produce results that are good enough for this application:

1. **Extract the red channel:** take the `input` RGB image, and extract the first channel. This is a gray-value image. We'll call this image `channel`.
2. **Apply a top-hat filter to detect the thin structures:** the difference between a closing with a small structuring element (SE) applied to `channel`, and `channel` (a closing is a dilation followed by an erosion with the same SE, you're using this to find lines as well). We'll call this output `thin`. `thin = closing(channel)-channel`. This step is similar to your local thresholding, but no actual threshold is applied. The resulting intensities indicate how dark the lines are w.r.t. to background. If you add `thin` to `channel`, you'll fill in these thin structures. The size of the SE here determines what is considered "thin".
3. **Filter out the short lines, to keep only the long ones:** apply an opening with a long horizontal SE to `thin`, and an opening with a long vertical SE to `thin`, and take the maximum of the two result. We'll call this `lines`. Note that this is the same process you used to generate `horizontal` and `vertical`. Instead of adding them together as Jeru suggested, we take the maximum. This makes it so that output intensities still match the contrast in `channel`. (In Mathematical Morphology parlance, the supremum of openings is an opening). The length of the SEs here determines what is long enough to be a line.
4. **Fill in the lines in the original image channel:** now simply add `lines` to `channel`. Write the result to the first channel of the output image.
5. **Repeat the same process with the other two channels.**

Using [DIPlib](https://diplib.org) this is quite a simple script:

```
import diplib as dip

input = dip.ImageReadTIFF('/home/cris/tmp/T4tbM.tif')
output = input.Copy()

for ii in range(0,3):
   channel = output.TensorElement(ii)
   thin = dip.Closing(channel, dip.SE(5, 'rectangular')) - channel
   vertical = dip.Opening(thin, dip.SE([100,1], 'rectangular'))
   horizontal = dip.Opening(thin, dip.SE([1,100], 'rectangular'))
   lines = dip.Supremum(vertical,horizontal)
   channel += lines # overwrites output image
```

**Edit:**

When increasing the size of the first SE, above set to 5, to be large enough to remove also the thicker gray bar in the middle of the example image, causes part of the block containing the inverted text "POWERLIFTING" to be left in `thin`.

To filter out those parts as well, we can change the definition of `thin` as follows:

```
notthin = dip.Closing(channel, dip.SE(11, 'rectangular'), ["add max"]))
notthin = dip.MorphologicalReconstruction(notthin, channel, 1, "erosion")
thin = notthin - channel
```

That is, instead of `thin=closing(channel)-channel`, we do `thin=reconstruct(closing(channel))-channel`. The reconstruction simply expands selected (not thin) structures so that where part of a structure was selected, now the full structure is selected. The only thing that is now in `thin` are lines that are not connected to thicker structures.

I've also added `"add max"` as a boundary condition -- this causes the closing to expand the area outside the image with white, and therefore see lines at the edges of the image as lines.

[image: output]

Comment: I am impressed with the in-depth detail! Is there a way to install this package using the `pip` command? BTW +1 for a more generalized approach !!

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. I checked the project on github as well. I will get in touch provided I can offer some help.

Comment: DIPlib can be installed with `pip install diplib`.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate more here is what to do:

- First, add the resulting images of `vertical` and `horizontal`. This will give you an image containing both the horizontal and vertical lines. Since both the images are of type `uint8` (unsigned 8-bit integer) adding them won't be a problem:

`res = vertical + horizontal`

- Finally, mask the resulting image obtained above with the original 3-channel image. This can be accomplished using `cv2.bitwise_and`:

`fin = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = cv2.bitwise_not(res))`

Comment: Thanks, Jeru. I tried to follow your advice, however if I try to save 'fin' the resulting image I get is this https://ibb.co/kDzm3d - any idea why? many thanks

Comment: @Dan Sorry my bad! Check the edit it has to be `cv2.bitwise_not(res)` as the mask.

Comment: thanks, I tried with your edit but the results is not what I expected: https://ibb.co/mkOh9J

Answer (score 2):

A sample for removing horizontal lines.

Sample image:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("Image path", 0)

if len(img.shape) != 2:
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
else:
    gray = img

gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
bw = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, 
cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15, -2)

horizontal = np.copy(bw)

cols = horizontal.shape[1]
horizontal_size = cols // 30

horizontalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (horizontal_size, 1))

horizontal = cv2.erode(horizontal, horizontalStructure)
horizontal = cv2.dilate(horizontal, horizontalStructure)

cv2.imwrite("horizontal_lines_extracted.png", horizontal)

horizontal_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(horizontal)
cv2.imwrite("inverse_extracted.png", horizontal_inv)

masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask=horizontal_inv)
masked_img_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(masked_img)

cv2.imwrite("masked_img.jpg", masked_img_inv)
```

=> horizontal_lines_extracted.png:

[image]

=> inverse_extracted.png

[image]

=> masked_img.png(resultant image after masking)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 170, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)#|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

V = cv2.Sobel(binary, cv2.CV_8U, dx=1, dy=0)
H = cv2.Sobel(binary, cv2.CV_8U, dx=0, dy=1)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
V = cv2.morphologyEx(V, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, iterations = 2)
H = cv2.morphologyEx(H, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, iterations = 2)

rows,cols = image.shape[:2]

mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)

contours = cv2.findContours(V, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]
for cnt in contours:
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    # manipulate these values to change accuracy
    if h > rows/2 and w < 10:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], -1, 255,-1)

contours = cv2.findContours(H, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]
for cnt in contours:
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    # manipulate these values to change accuracy
    if w > cols/2 and h < 10:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], -1, 255,-1)

mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, iterations = 2)
image[mask == 255] = (255,255,255)
```

[image: result]

Comment: thanks, this works for this particular image. Would you be able to add a bit of commentary to explain the process? I'm quite new to OpenCV. Also, do you have any suggestions for images that have background or lines of different colours and lenghts? I've tried to run it on a few different ones and results were quite poor. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: One example I tried is this, where only the left vertical line was identified
http://nikulsinha.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/news-article001.jpg 
or this, where none of the black lines were covered  https://www.teachitenglish.co.uk/attachments/thumbnails/big/x14219.php.pagespeed.ic.LjLPBUNgIK.jpg