# Remove horizontal lines with Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to remove horizontal lines from my daughter's drawings, but can't get it quite right.

The approach I am following is creating a mask with horizontal lines (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57410471/1873521) and then removing that mask from the original (https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html).

As you can see in the pics below, this only partially removes the horizontal lines, and also creates a few distortions, as some of the original drawing horizontal-ish lines also end up in the mask.

Any help improving this approach would be greatly appreciated!

### Create mask with horizontal lines

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/57410471/1873521

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("input.png", 0)

if len(img.shape) != 2:
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
else:
    gray = img

gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
bw = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, 
cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15, -2)

horizontal = np.copy(bw)

cols = horizontal.shape[1]
horizontal_size = cols // 30

horizontalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (horizontal_size, 1))

horizontal = cv2.erode(horizontal, horizontalStructure)
horizontal = cv2.dilate(horizontal, horizontalStructure)

cv2.imwrite("horizontal_lines_extracted.png", horizontal)
```

### Remove horizontal lines using mask

From https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
mask = cv2.imread('horizontal_lines_extracted.png',0)
dst = cv2.inpaint(img,mask,3,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
cv2.imwrite("original_unmasked.png", dst)
```

## Pics

#### Original picture

[image: Original picture]

#### Mask

[image]

#### Partially cleaned:

[image: Partially cleaned]

Comment: inpainting is certainly a good idea, though the two implemented algorithms create something "diffuse". they can't replicate texture. -- you might want to calculate finer masks. those lines you want to remove are fairly thin, and everything you _don't_ want to remove isn't that thin. -- if you don't need this fully automated, you could manually define those masks... open the scans in a photo editor, add a layer, paint a mask on top, and only keep the layer you just painted.

Comment: The lines may not be perfectly horizontal. Have you tried thickening the lines in your mask using morphology dilate?

Comment: Thanks @nathancy sadly it does not seem to work. The detected_lines images is mostly the hair of the character... :(

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz , I have a ton of these drawings, so a fully automated pipeline would be much better.

Comment: @fmw42 , I edited the original image making the lines completely horizontal, but that does not seem to help much. I am a complete noob, how could I go about thickening the lines?

Comment: morphology dilate will thicken the mask lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, I saw that working on the drawing separated from the paper would lead to a better result. I used MORPH_CLOSE to work on the paper and MORPH_OPEN for the lines in the inner part. I hope your daughter likes it :)

```
img = cv2.imread(r'E:\Downloads\i0RDA.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Remove horizontal lines
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,81,17)
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (25,1))

# Using morph close to get lines outside the drawing
remove_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, horizontal_kernel, iterations=3)
cnts = cv2.findContours(remove_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
mask = np.zeros(gray.shape, np.uint8)
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255),2)

# First inpaint
img_dst = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 3, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
```

[image]

[image]

```
gray_dst = cv2.cvtColor(img_dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray_dst, 50, 150, apertureSize = 3)
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15,1))

# Using morph open to get lines inside the drawing
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel)
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
mask = np.uint8(img_dst)
mask = np.zeros(gray_dst.shape, np.uint8)
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255),2)

# Second inpaint
img2_dst = cv2.inpaint(img_dst, mask, 3, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: For some reason this is the result I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLoLC.jpg Could it be that we use a different input image? Or different OpenCV versions?

Comment: I currently use 4.5.5. Is yours different?

Comment: No, we have the same version. This is strange.

Comment: That's weird! I've just retried the code. Everything looks perfect. Let's see how it looks for other people.

Comment: @AnnZen I can confirm I'm getting the same output as Esraa. Looks pretty good: https://i.imgur.com/sPEWU6q.png. OpenCV version: 4.5.1, using input image posted by OP.

Comment: Oh! I just realized I was using the second image posted by the OP!

Comment: Happy to hear that everything is perfect now. :)

Comment: @esraa-abdelmaksoud this is fantastic! I can reproduce it for this drawing without issues. My daughter is losing her mind over how many wonderful people there are helping with this. <3

Comment: That's awesome! You made my day Gorka! I love to draw since being young so I understand how important this is to her. ❤️

Answer (score 3):

1. Get the Edges
2. Dilate to close the lines
3. Hough line to detect the lines
4. Filter out the non horizontal lines
5. Inpaint the mask
6. Getting the Edges

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize=3)
```

[image]

2. Dilate to close the lines

```
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(edges, np.ones((3,3), np.uint8), iterations=1)
```

[image]

3. Hough line to detect the lines

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
            img_dilation, # Input edge image
            1, # Distance resolution in pixels
            np.pi/180, # Angle resolution in radians
            threshold=100, # Min number of votes for valid line
            minLineLength=5, # Min allowed length of line
            maxLineGap=10 # Max allowed gap between line for joining them
            )
```

4. Filter out the non horizontal lines  using slope.

```
lines_list = []

for points in lines:
    x1,y1,x2,y2=points[0]
    lines_list.append([(x1,y1),(x2,y2)])
    slope = ((y2-y1) / (x2-x1)) if (x2-x1) != 0 else np.inf
    
    if slope <= 1:
        cv2.line(mask,(x1,y1),(x2,y2), color=(255, 255, 255),thickness = 2)
```

5. Inpaint the mask

```
result = cv2.inpaint(image,mask,3,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
```

[image]

Full Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
 
# Read image
image = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
mask = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)

# Convert image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
# Use canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize=3)

# Dilating
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(edges, np.ones((3,3), np.uint8), iterations=1)

 
# Apply HoughLinesP method to
# to directly obtain line end points
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
            img_dilation, # Input edge image
            1, # Distance resolution in pixels
            np.pi/180, # Angle resolution in radians
            threshold=100, # Min number of votes for valid line
            minLineLength=5, # Min allowed length of line
            maxLineGap=10 # Max allowed gap between line for joining them
            )

lines_list = []

for points in lines:
    x1,y1,x2,y2=points[0]
    lines_list.append([(x1,y1),(x2,y2)])
    slope = ((y2-y1) / (x2-x1)) if (x2-x1) != 0 else np.inf
    
    if slope <= 1:
        cv2.line(mask,(x1,y1),(x2,y2), color=(255, 255, 255),thickness = 2)
    
result = cv2.inpaint(image,mask,3,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It is so close! I am tweaking the HoughLinesP() parameters to avoid the distortion in the drawing lines, but can't seem to find a way :(

Comment: After tinkering a bit more, I can see I will probably need a specific set of parameters for each image. Thanks a lot @cyborg !

Comment: I don't understand. When I ran your code I got https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXOGt.jpg Which image did you use as the input image?

Comment: I used the same image in the question. May be a different opencv version.

Comment: Oh! I just realized I was using the second image posted by the OP!

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to define an HSV mask that only masks out the needed details *(in this case, they are the person, the sparkles, and the signature)*.

After obtaining the proper mask, simply blur the image in the unmasked parts. Here is the result with the HSV mask of lower bounds `0, 0, 160` and upper bounds `116, 30, 253`:

[image]

Here is the processing of the image, in this order:

(Original image), (Mask),
(Blurred image), (Resulting masked image):

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("input.jpg")
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 0, 160])
upper = np.array([116, 30, 253])
mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)
img_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (31, 31), 10)
img_blurred[mask == 0] = img[mask == 0]

cv2.imshow("Result", img_blurred)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

As you can see, the squiggly lines in the person's hair turned out thinner than it's supposed to be. This can be fixed with a few erode iterations of the binary mask *(simply add `mask = cv2.erode(mask, np.ones((3, 3)), 3)` to the code under the definition of the `mask` variable)*:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("input.jpg")

img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower = np.array([0, 0, 160])
upper = np.array([116, 30, 253])

mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)
mask = cv2.erode(mask, np.ones((3, 3)), 3)
img_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (31, 31), 10)
img_blurred[mask == 0] = img[mask == 0]

cv2.imshow("Result", img_blurred)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image]

The process in the same order again:

[image]
[image]

I've added a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71475904/13552470) to include the program that you can use to tweak the values and see the results in real-time, in case you have other images you want to apply the same method to.

Comment: Note that this is using the partially processed image in the OP's post as input.

Answer (score 2):

An extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71475446/13552470) answer, here is the program that will allow you to apply the same method *(of masking out the needed details of the image, applying blur to the image, and replacing the masked-out parts of the image with the original image)* onto any image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def show(imgs, win="Image", scale=1):
    imgs = [cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) \
            if len(img.shape) == 2 \
            else img for img in imgs]
    img_concat = np.concatenate(imgs, 1)
    h, w = img_concat.shape[:2]
    cv2.imshow(win, cv2.resize(img_concat, (int(w * scale), int(h * scale))))

d = {"Hue Min": (0, 179),
     "Hue Max": (116, 179),
     "Sat Min": (0, 255),
     "Sat Max": (30, 255),
     "Val Min": (160, 255),
     "Val Max": (253, 255),
     "k1": (31, 50),
     "k2": (31, 50),
     "sigma": (10, 20)}

img = cv2.imread(r"input.jpg")
cv2.namedWindow("Track Bars")
for i in d:
    cv2.createTrackbar(i, "Track Bars", *d[i], id)

img = cv2.imread("input.jpg")

img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
while True:
    h_min, h_max, s_min, s_max, v_min, v_max, k1, k2, s = (cv2.getTrackbarPos(i, "Track Bars") for i in d)
    lower = np.array([h_min, s_min, v_min])
    upper = np.array([h_max, s_max, v_max])
    mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, np.ones((3, 3)))
    k1, k2 = k1 // 2 * 2 + 1, k2 // 2 * 2 + 1
    img_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (k1, k2), s)
    result = img_blurred.copy()
    result[mask == 0] = img[mask == 0]
    show([img, mask], "Window 1", 0.5) # Show original image & mask
    show([img_blurred, result], "Window 2", 0.5) # Show blurred image & result
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
```

Demonstration of running the program:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ann-zen This is very helpful! I love the interactive widget.